# Create new product relation / custom product relation magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to create a new tab in the admin area for product details where I can use a custom product relation. I am already using Upsell, Related and Cross-sell but would need an extra relation between products.

Just wondering if anyone else has come against this issue/requirement and can point me in the right direction on creating a new product relation.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, Do you meant to ask you need a way to assign some product as we have with upsell, related etc.. in product edit mode and with separate tab ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! Basically another form of relating products with a seperate tab.

Comment: Take a look at github.com/magepal/link-product

Answer (score 0):

For this type of requirements you need to get developed an extension which is generated tab, database table to hold main product and their relation.

Thanks,
sagar

Answer (score 0):

There is a good sample in Magento 1 version [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/). However, in Magento 2, there are some notes if we're trying to follow the logic from this guide:

--Replaced event `catalog_product_prepare_save` with controller product initialization helper that can be customized via plugins - `Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Initialization/Helper/ProductLinks.php`.
--Replaced event `catalog_model_product_duplicate` with composite `Product\Copier` model. However, we don't use this event.
--We need to override the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Link\Proxy` - can find it under `var/generation`.

We can read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-product-relations).